# Multiply the row values by the inputted value

Tags: javascript

I have the following HTML

```
<form><input type="number"></form>
<table class="my-table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td>Header 1</td>
        <td>Header 2</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr data-row-num="1">
        <td>Item 1</td>
        <td>£0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-row-num="1">
        <td>Item 2</td>
        <td>£5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-row-num="1">
        <td>Item 3</td>
        <td>£10</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I need to multiple the values of each td:last-child  by the inputted value above, and display there new values. I had experiments with js, but I am really bad at it

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('input[type=number]').on("input", function () {
var tr = $('input[type=number]').closest('tr');
var num = this.value;
var numerator = tr.find('td:second-child').text();
tr.find('td:last-child').text('£' + num * numerator);
```

});

Thank you so much!

Comment: If they are initially zero, the multiplication will also be zero. No need to do anything.

Comment: Have you tried any JS?

Comment: They are not initially zero

Comment: where you want to display?

Comment: I tried, but it wasn't a successful try

Comment: There are a lot of ways you could do this, what have you tried yourself? Post what you have, it shows that you're making an effort and people will be much more happy to help :)

Comment: i want to replace the values in the td:last-child

Comment: This smells like a homework assignment. Unfortunately, StackOverflow isn't usually for problems like that. We can give you some guidance, but you have to show that you've put in some effort. Just saying "I tried but it didn't work" typically isn't good enough.

Answer (score 0):

Put your price in `span` to have a better display and [selector](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), and use [jQuery `.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) to loop through your prices

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="myForm"><input type="number" id="myNumber" value="5"><input type="submit" value="Do"></form>
        <table class="my-table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>Header 1</td>
                    <td>Header 2</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr data-row-num="1">
                    <td>Item 1</td>
                    <td>£<span class="price">10</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr data-row-num="1">
                    <td>Item 2</td>
                    <td>£<span class="price">100</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr data-row-num="1">
                    <td>Item 3</td>
                    <td>£<span class="price">1000</span></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#myForm ').submit(function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();

                    // add attribute 'step="0.01"' to input, if you need to use parseFloat()
                    var input = parseInt($(this).find('#myNumber').val());
                    $('.my-table tr td > span.price').each(function (k, item) {
                        var current = parseInt($(item).text());
                        $(item).text(current * input);
                    });
                    return false;
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/39mmgwvd/1/)

Comment: If you're adding the `.price` class, the `$('.my-table tr td > span.price')` seems a bit overkill, you could probably just use `$('.price')`.

Comment: A more specific selector will be faster to find in DOM. Just think of a complex html page.

Comment: True, but given the level of this question I would value simplicity over optimisation.

Comment: It works fine in Fiddle, but when I copy the code in the html page, there is a error in Firebug:
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
$('#myForm ').submit(function(e){

Comment: Edited my answer with full html page

Comment: Yes, I already got it. Just forgot to close the tag. Thanks so much

Comment: You should mark the answer if it solved your problem